# Recursão no R erro

Tags: r

Eu tenho a seguinte função recursiva:

```
tamanho <- function(v){
  if (is.null(v)){
    return(0)
  }
  i <- tamanho(v[-1])+1
  return(i)
}
```

Estou usando o RStudio, e quando chamo a função com esse exemplo:

```
tamanho(c(1,2,3,5))
```

dá o seguinte erro, e o R "reseta":

> **R Session Aborted**
>   R encountered a fatal error.
>   The session was terminated.
>   [Start New Session]

[image: Imagem do erro]

Comment: Você está rodando no R ou no RStudio?

Comment: Estou rodando no RStudio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A tua função tem um problema de lógica. Se `v` é nulo, está tudo certo: ela para. Mas se `v` não for nulo, ela vai continuar fazendo a recursão indefinidamente. Suponha, como no teu exemplo, que `v <- c(1,2,3,5)`:

```
v <- c(1, 2, 3, 5)
v[-1]
[1] 2 3 5
```

`v[-1]` é o vetor `v` sem o primeiro elemento. O segundo passo da tua função recursiva é eliminar o segundo elemento, o que é equivalente a

```
v[-1][-1]
[1] 3 5
```

E isso dá certo, pois o `R` entende que `v[-1]` é um vetor e, portanto, é possível retirar a sua primeira posição, como foi possível fazer isso com `v`. Mas veja o que acontece se fizermos isso um número maior de vezes:

```
v
[1] 1 2 3 5
v[-1]
[1] 2 3 5
v[-1][-1]
[1] 3 5
v[-1][-1][-1]
[1] 5
v[-1][-1][-1][-1]
numeric(0)
v[-1][-1][-1][-1][-1]
numeric(0)
v[-1][-1][-1][-1][-1][-1]
numeric(0)
```

Perceba que a partir do momento em que `v` é exaurido, o `R` continua a tentar calcular o seu tamanho, mesmo que não haja tamanho algum para ser calculado, que é o que ocorre a partir de `v[-1][-1][-1][-1]`. Isso ocorre porque, mesmo não tendo elemento algum, `v[-1][-1][-1][-1]` não é nulo:

```
is.null(v[-1][-1][-1][-1])
[1] FALSE
```

Portanto, teu programa não tem critério de parada, pois `is.null` não serve para o propósito desejado. Tanto que, ao rodar o teu código original no terminal, em vez de acontecer um crash como no RStudio, a resposta de erro que obtenho é a seguinte:

```
tamanho(c(1, 2, 3, 5))
Error: C stack usage  7969280 is too close to the limit
```

Ou seja, a pilha estoura (aka stack overflow).

Dá pra resolver isso com uma pequena mudança no teu código:

```
tamanho <- function(v){
  i <- 0
  if (!identical(v, numeric(0))){
    i <- tamanho(v[-1]) + 1
  }
  return(i)
}

v <- c(1, 2, 3, 5)
tamanho(v)
[1] 4
```

`identical(v, numeric(0))` vai testar se a recursão de `v` chega em `numeric(0)` em algum momento. `!` vai negar isso. Portanto, a recursão vai parar apenas quando `numeric(0)` for verdadeiro.

Devido ao teste utilizar `numeric(0)` como condição de parada, este código serve apenas para calcular comprimentos de vetores numéricos. Fica a cargo do leitor implementar uma versão geral dele, para vetores de caracteres, inteiros, lógicos etc.

Comment: Eu até pensei nisso, mas achei que utilizar a própria `length` dentro da função `tamanho`  seria uma pequena trapaça. Afinal, a ideia da função `tamanho` é, justamente, substituir a função `length`.

Comment: O objetivo dessa função é justamente criar uma função length